# Suggestions for documentation for end users

Tags: documentation

I am looking for any suggestions or recommendations of where I could direct new-to-Joomla end users who want to make changes to their website that I have built for them. Something that gives content to Joomla & CMS's, Articles, Menus, Modules and how to edit them, that there is a front end and back end, and why uploading pictures isn't as simple as using Faceboook or Instagram etc.

I have looked at the Joomla Docs pages and it is more about getting started with installing your Joomla environment but what I am looking for is targeted at people who just want to edit their content and maybe add some more content while someone else, me, looks after all that other stuff.

TIA,
Terry

Comment: Have you tried the built-in Help functionality? Help button appears in the toolbar of most administrator pages.

Comment: @Sharky I hadn't looked recently and while the Help is a lot better than i remember it, it only addresses some of what  I am looking for.